# Primefaces LazyScheduleModel - Unordered list of events

Tags: jsf, primefaces, schedule

i'm using Primefaces 3.5.17 (unfortunately i can't change the version) and trying to implement a scheduler using the LazyScheduleModel.
The problem is that the events are rendered in an unordered way (basically i've the same 3 events in all the involved days).
[image: unordered events in scheduler]

Any suggestion on how to solve that?

Thanks
Davide

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve] and https://www.stackoverflow.com and improve your question

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, all the events had the same start date and so the random ordering happened.
So on every single event i've added 1 second on the start date from the previous one, and i got the expected result.